# Do you need kabolo (permission/licence) for checking the lungs

Tags: halacha, slaughter-shochet-shecht

I understand (from simla chadasha [1.5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&pgnum=10) )  I need kabolo for shehita (I am not allowed to shecht without permission from a Rav, the rabonim made a hairum that people are not allowed to shecht without kabolo)
But do I need one for bedika (the mitzva of the checking of the lungs)?
Or something similar to it

Comment: It's hard to call checking the lungs a Mitzva. It's more a coincidence of the current local average bovine health situation. In a different time or place or species, it could be other things (or none) that need to be checked.

Comment: @DoubleAA D"n I will send you a source that it is a mitzva dirabonon

Comment: @DoubleAA mate osher [18.2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&pgnum=65) - [39.3](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&pgnum=188) please tell me if I am wrong (as you probably will anyway)

Comment: What did observant Jews do in isolated locations hundreds of years ago?

Comment: @JJLL Received permission from there rabbis or the decree forbidding it did not reach them (so they did not have to keep it)

Comment: Ordinarily, permission to slaughter ("*kabbalah*") was granted for slaughtering and examining together, regardless if the recipient intended to only slaughter or only examine.

Answer (score 1):

The Shulchan Aruch states clearly that the same requirement for kabala applies to checking the lungs.

Comment: Where does the SA mention any sort of *kabbalah* at all? Do you mean Rema?

Comment: Yes, in the rema on sif alef. Sorry, I meant “the Shulchan Aruch” as in the Sefer, as opposed to the author. I’m used to referring to the beis Yosef as the mechaber. I’ll try to be more specific in the future.

Comment: @DovidShaffier Understood. I was being specific bec particularly in this regard (kabbalah) Ashkenazi tradition was different than Sephardic.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.1.1